# Cancel common factors in symbolic product

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, products

Suppose I have the following function

```
G[n_, k_] := Product[g[n + i]/g[i], {i, 0, k}]
```

where $n,k$ are assumed to be natural numbers and $g$ is a nonzero symbolic function. I want to simplify the expression `G[n,k+1]/G[n,k]` and cancel all common terms to get `g[n+k+1]/g[k+1]`. However, `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Expand` and `Cancel` all yield the symbolic (not cancelled) product.

Comment: You could achieve this by an additional rule: ` G[n, k + 1] := G[n, k] g[n + k + 1]/g[k + 1]`

Comment: Thanks! But then I would have to specify this relation myself. The goal is to let Mathematica simplify it (it is a very simple cancellation so I don't see why we should need to add any "human insight").

Comment: `DiscreteRatio` is intended for this. `In[194]:= gG[n_, k_] := Product[g[n + i]/g[i], {i, 0, k}]

In[199]:= DiscreteRatio[gG[n, k], k]

Out[199]= g[1 + k + n]/g[1 + k]`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works well for the example at hand. However, it is not quite what i was looking for as it seems to not really simplify certain expression. E.g. `DiscreteRatio[gG[n, k], n]` does not simplify to `g[n+1+k]/g[n]` as one might hope/expect. Is there a way to make it work for that shift as well (i.e., if the expression in the product is shifted and not just the range of the product).

Comment: Also higher step sizes are not simplified, e.g. `DiscreteRatio[gG[n, k], {k, 1, 2}]` does not simplify.